# geokit rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a hostmonster account, where I installed geokit as a gem.
When I try to find location based on IP, i get "Unknow City" for the city field.
This happens on my local machine as well, where it shows "Private Address" for city.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced IpGeocoder in my code with MultiGeocoder and it worked.
Tried different geocoder providers (Yahoo, Gooogle) but MultiGeocoder seems to be the most accurate.